# sip register success on one host but fail on another host in same local network

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I acquired antisip account and setup asterisk (lets say PBX-A) to register. It worked fine.
However, I attempted to do so with another asterisk (PBX-B). No luck this time.
PBX-A and PBX-B are on the same local network behind NAT.

Here is the result of several commands on PBX-B

```
localhost*CLI> sip show registry
Host                  dnsmgr Username       Refresh State         Reg.Time
sip.antisip.com:5060  N      username          120 Request Sent
1 SIP registrations.

localhost*CLI> sip show peers
Name/username      Host          Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status      Description
username/username  91.121.78.130     Yes        Yes            5060     UNREACHABLE
```

I did tcpdump to check the registration signal. PBX-B does send the signal to the sip server though no return.

```
[root@localhost sysconfig]# tcpdump  port 5060
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
16:15:00.074161 IP 192.168.1.207.sip > sip.antisip.com.sip: SIP, length: 390
16:15:04.074820 IP 192.168.1.207.sip > sip.antisip.com.sip: SIP, length: 390
16:15:06.438076 IP 192.168.1.207.sip > sip.antisip.com.sip: SIP, length: 549
```

I can ping to the sip server.

```
[root@localhost sysconfig]# ping sip.antisip.com
PING sip.antisip.com (91.121.78.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sip.antisip.com (91.121.78.130): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=169 ms
64 bytes from sip.antisip.com (91.121.78.130): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=169 ms
```

I check if it works by port forwarding UDP ports 5060,10000-2000 though still no luck. By the way, PBX-A is working fine without port forwarding. Then I noticed that PBX-B includes iptables so I check the configuration of the fire wall and enabled several ports like this:

```
[root@localhost sysconfig]# service iptables status
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:10000:20000
2    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5060

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Probably it does not do any work since originally all INPUT was ACCEPTED... And of course, it changes nothing.

I use same conf file under /etc/asterisk for the local PBXs. They are in same network. So I can only think up is the firewall setting of PBX-B. But still there must be another issue.
I highly appreciate if you give me some tip on this.

Here is the sip.conf setting.

```
[general]
register => username:pass@sip.antisip.com/username

[vivinavi]
nat=yes
insecure=port,invite
canreinvite=no
username=username
host=sip.antisip.com
fromdomain=sip.antisip.com
fromuser=username
type=friend
context=antisip
secret=pass
qualify=yes
```

Followings are the software version of both box.
PBX-A : Asterisk 11.10.2, SHMZ release 6.5  (FreePBX 2.11.0.38)
PBX-B : Asterisk 11.7.0, Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS